# Playing regular and looping sounds with JDK 11?

Tags: codenameone

I am using Java JDK 11.0.8 ("Installed JREs" under Eclipse is set to jdk-11.0.8), Eclipse 2020-06, and Codename One 6.0.0.

I have recently switched from JDK 8 to JDK 11 and noticed that playing sounds option in my app does not work anymore...

Note that I uncheck "Java 8" when I create my app and I am only trying to work things out in the simulator (I am not trying to deploy the app to an actual mobile device).

I want to play a "regular sound" (I want to play a sound from beginning to end, and when it ends I do not need to replay it from the beginning) and also a "looping sound" (the sound should come to its beginning when it ends and hence, I can continuously play it in the background).

Hence I have two questions:

**Question1 - About "regular sounds"**

I would like to create Media object just once and then re-use it whenever I need to play the same regular sound.

For that purpose I am encapsulating a Media creation inside a class as follows:

```
public class RegularSound {
    private Media m;
    public RegularSound(String fileName) {
        try{
        InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/"+fileName);
        m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/wav");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void play() {
        m.setTime(0);
        m.play();
    }
}
```

Then I instantiate the RegularSound object and play it as follows:

```
mySound = new RegularSound("example.wav");
mySound.play();
```

Please note that example.wav is copied directly under the "src" directory of my project.

This code used to work with JDK 8, but with JDK 11, I get the following build errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/ControllerListener
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaJMFSEPort$1.run(JavaJMFSEPort.java:67)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.media.ControllerListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findSystemClass(ClassLoader.java:1247)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.findClass(ClassPathLoader.java:269)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:115)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.ClassPathLoader.loadClass(ClassPathLoader.java:107)
    ... 14 more
```

**Question2- About "looping sounds"**

For looping sound I have created another class as follows:

```
public class LoopingSound implements Runnable{
    private Media m;
    String fileName;
    
    public LoopingSound(String fileName){
        try{
            InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/"+fileName);
            m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/wav",this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    public void pause()
        {
        m.pause();
        }
    public void play()
        {
        m.play();
        }
    
    public void run() {
        m.setTime(0);
        m.play();
            
    }
}
```

But I again get build errors when I instantiate an object of LoopingSound and try to play it...

So could you please let me know how to change code for regular and looping sounds so that I do not receive above-mentioned errors when using JDK 11?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the reply @shai-almog. I have installed CEF. But I am receiving some messages on the console in runtime and I can't hear the sound playing... I run the following code:

```
try {
            InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/example.wav");
            Media m = MediaManager.createMedia(is, "audio/wav");
            m.play();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and I receive the following messages on console when I run this code (it throws an exception at the end):

```
Adding CEF to classpath
Retina Scale: 2.0
CEF Args: [--disable-gpu, --disable-software-rasterizer, --disable-gpu-compositing, --touch-events=enabled, --enable-media-stream, --device-scale-factor=4, --force-device-scale-factor=4, --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required, --enable-usermedia-screen-capturing]
Using:
JCEF Version = 83.4.0.260
CEF Version = 83.4.0
Chromium Version = 83.0.4103.106
AppHandler.stateHasChanged: INITIALIZING
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path C:\Users\pmuyan\.codenameone\cef\lib\win64
Added scheme search://
Added scheme client://
Added scheme cn1stream://

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:8088/devtools/browser/591d3502-6fd6-4997-9131-9a2a352e47b1
AppHandler.stateHasChanged: INITIALIZED
Running ready callbacks
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Address changed to data:text/html,%3C!doctype%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cstyle%20type%3D'text%2Fcss'%3Edocument%2C%20body%20%7Bpadding%3A0%3Bmargin%3A0%3B%20width%3A100%25%3B%20height%3A%20100%25%7D%20video%2C%20audio%20%7Bmargin%3A0%3B%20padding%3A0%3B%20width%3A100%25%3B%20height%3A%20100%25%7D%3C%2Fstyle%3E%3C%2Fhead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Caudio%20id%3D'cn1Media'%20width%3D'640'%20height%3D'480'%20style%3D'width%3A100%25%3Bheight%3A100%25'%20src%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fcn1app%2Fstreams%2F1'%2F%3E%3Cscript%3Ewindow.cn1Media%20%3D%20document.getElementById('cn1Media')%3Bfunction%20callback(data)%7B%20cefQuery(%7Brequest%3A'shouldNavigate%3A'%2BJSON.stringify(data)%2C%20onSuccess%3A%20function(response)%7B%7D%2C%20onFailure%3Afunction(error_code%2C%20error_message)%20%7B%20console.log(error_message)%7D%7D)%3B%7Dcn1Media.addEventListener('pause'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'state'%3A'paused'%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('play'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'state'%3A'playing'%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('ended'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'state'%3A'ended'%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('durationchange'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'duration'%3A%20Math.floor(cn1Media.duration%20*%201000)%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('timeupdate'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'time'%3A%20Math.floor(cn1Media.currentTime%20*%201000)%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('volumechange'%2C%20function()%7B%20callback(%7B'volume'%3A%20Math.round(cn1Media.volume%20*%20100)%7D)%7D)%3Bcn1Media.addEventListener('error'%2C%20function()%7B%20var%20msg%20%3D%20'Unknown%20Error'%3B%20try%20%7Bmsg%20%3D%20cn1Media.error.message%20%2B%20'.%20Code%3D'%2Bcn1Media.error.code%3B%7Dcatch(e)%7B%7D%20callback(%7B'error'%3A%20msg%7D)%7D)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%20%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E
```

**UPDATE 2**

I could manually add Open JavaFX 11 to Eclipse and to Codename One app running under Eclipse while using JDK 11 as follows:

```
Step1) Create JavaFX11 user library under Eclipse
Download JavaFX 11 from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/
unzip it -> creates javafx-sdk-11.0.2 folder
Create a User Library: Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries -> New. 
Name it JavaFX11.
Hit "Add External JARs" and include all the jars under javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib

Step 2) Add the JavaFX11 library to the project:
Right click on project.
Select Build path -> Configure Build Path 
Goto Library tab->Add Library->User Library->Check JavaFX11->Apply and Close
```

Now, I can hear sounds playing in my Codename One application.

However, I need to run my application from command prompt and regular command line to run the apps does not work anymore (the app cannot find the JavaFX related classes from the command prompt and I get the same errors listed above). So could you please tell me how to modify the command line so that Codename One project that uses JavaFX would run from command prompt?

Here is the regular command line I use:

```
java -cp dist\Proj.jar;JavaSE.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.mycompany.hi.Main
```

BTW, I have tried to add javafx.media.jar under javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib to the classpath (-cp) in the command line, but this did not work...

**UPDATE 3**

We have solved the issue by using the following command line:

java --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\ --add-modules= ALL-MODULE-PATH -cp dist\Proj.jar;JavaSE.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.mycompany.hi.Main

(where C:\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\ is our )

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TL;DR

Either install CEF as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/big-changes-jcef.html) or switch to ZuluFX 11 for your VM.

The explanation:

This used to work until we integrated CEF support we would download JavaFX dynamically for JDK 11 installs but this caused a lot of related problems. So we decided to migrate to CEF, this is still in progress and while it's ongoing JavaFX dynamic download is broken. Once it's done CEF will be auto-installed and this will be seamless again.

This impacts browser component and media which are the two components implemented by JavaFX.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE in my question. I still have problems and would appreciate your help...

Comment: This could be a bug in CEF. Please file an issue here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

In this case you will have to delete CEF and use a VM that supports JavaFX. You might be able to manually install JavaFX into your VM or just download ZuluFX.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer @shai-almog. I have filed the issue at GitHub. Also, I was successful at adding JavaFX to Eclipse and Codename One project running under Eclipse. However, now I am having issues with running the app from the command prompt. Please see **UPDATE 2** in my question. I would again appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: Make sure the java command is the one from ZuluFX. If that doesn't work try adding jfxrt.jar from your JDK install to the classpath.